# D3.js-Treemap graph: How to use a json which is of different heirarchy from the one provided in flare.json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, d3.js

I am looking for a solution to implement the below json into treemap using d3.js.

The code i am using is :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

body {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  width: 960px;
}

form {
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  top: 10px;
}

.node {
  border: solid 1px white;
  font: 10px sans-serif;
  line-height: 12px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  text-indent: 2px;
}

</style>
<form>
  <label><input type="radio" name="mode" value="size" checked> Size</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="mode" value="count"> Count</label>

</form>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script src="file:///home/harsha/Downloads/test.json"></script>
<script>

var margin = {top: 40, right: 10, bottom: 10, left: 10},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var color = d3.scale.category20c();

var treemap = d3.layout.treemap()
    .size([width, height])
    .sticky(true)
    .value(function(d) { return d.size; });

var div = d3.select("body").append("div")
    .style("position", "relative")
    .style("width", (width + margin.left + margin.right) + "px")
    .style("height", (height + margin.top + margin.bottom) + "px")
    .style("left", margin.left + "px")
    .style("top", margin.top + "px");



d3.json("test.json", function(error, root) {

  if (error) throw error;

  var node = div.datum(root).selectAll(".node")
      .data(treemap.nodes)
    .enter().append("div")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .call(position)
      .style("background", function(d) { return d.children ? color(d.name) : null; })
      .text(function(d) { return d.children ? null : d.name; });

  d3.selectAll("input").on("change", function change() {
    var value = this.value === "count"
        ? function() { return 1; }
        : function(d) { return d.size; };

    node
        .data(treemap.value(value).nodes)
      .transition()
        .duration(1500)
        .call(position);
  });
});

function position() {
  this.style("left", function(d) { return d.x + "px"; })
      .style("top", function(d) { return d.y + "px"; })
      .style("width", function(d) { return Math.max(0, d.dx - 1) + "px"; })
      .style("height", function(d) { return Math.max(0, d.dy - 1) + "px"; });
}

</script>
```

The json used is:

```
{
  "name" : "Retail",
  "children" : [{
  "name" : "Services",
  "size" : 504
  }]
},
{
  "name" : "Business Services",
  "children" : [{
  "name" : "Services",
  "size" : 611352
  }]
},
{
  "name" : "Insurance",
  "children" : [{
  "name" : "Software",
  "size" : 33496
  }]
},
{
  "name" : "Manufacturing",
  "children" : [{
  "name" : "Maintenance",
  "size" : 588
  }]
},
{
  "name" : "Insurance",
  "children" : [{
  "name" : "Software",
  "size" : 9240
  }]
},
{
  "name" : "Computer Hardware",
  "children" : [{
  "name" : "Software",
  "size" : 5488
  }]
},
{
  "name" : "Retail",
  "children" : [{
  "name" : "Software",
  "size" : 27104
  }]
},
{
  "name" : "Storage",
  "children" : [{
  "name" : "Software",
  "size" : 9296
  }]
},
{
  "name" : "Financial Services",
  "children" : [{
  "name" : "Services",
  "size" : 1491
  }]
},


{
  "name" : "Computer Hardware",
  "children" : [{
  "name" : "Software",
  "size" : 2400
  }]
},
{
  "name" : "Distribution",
  "children" : [{
  "name" : "Software",
  "size" : 3840
  }]
},
{
  "name" : "Computer Hardware",
  "children" : [{
  "name" : "Software",
  "size" : 12160
  }]
},
{
  "name" : "Entertainment",
  "children" : [{
  "name" : "Services",
  "size" : 1218
  }]
},
{
  "name" : "Entertainment",
  "children" : [{
  "name" : "Software",
  "size" : 6264
  }]
},
{
  "name" : "Insurance",
  "children" : [{
  "name" : "Software",
  "size" : 14976
  }]
},
{
  "name" : "Business Services",
  "children" : [{
  "name" : "Software",
  "size" : 25760
  }]
},
{
  "name" : "Telecommunication",
  "children" : [{
  "name" : "Services",
  "size" : 10374
  }]
},
{
  "name" : "Recreation",
  "children" : [{
  "name" : "Maintenance",
  "size" : 823.2
  }]
},
{
  "name" : "Financial Services",
  "children" : [{
  "name" : "Software",
  "size" : 6408
  }]
},
{
  "name" : "Financial Services",
  "children" : [{
  "name" : "Maintenance",
  "size" : 1892.4
  }]
},
{
  "name" : "Healthcare",
  "children" : [{
  "name" : "Software",
  "size" : 4864
  }]
},
{
  "name" : "Financial Services",
  "children" : [{
  "name" : "Software",
  "size" : 11696
  }]
},
{
  "name" : "Financial Services",
  "children" : [{
  "name" : "Software",
  "size" : 3440
  }]
},
{
  "name" : "Computer Hardware",
  "children" : [{
  "name" : "Software",
  "size" : 107136
  }]
},
{
  "name" : "Distribution",
  "children" : [{
  "name" : "Software",
  "size" : 680
  }]
},
{
  "name" : "Business Services",
  "children" : [{
  "name" : "Maintenance",
  "size" : 2995.2
  }]
},
{
  "name" : "Insurance",
  "children" : [{
  "name" : "Software",
  "size" : 6160
  }]
},
{
  "name" : "Insurance",
  "children" : [{
  "name" : "Software",
  "size" : 28224
  }]
},
{
  "name" : "Telecommunication",
  "children" : [{
  "name" : "Software",
  "size" : 784
  }]
},
{
  "name" : "Insurance",
  "children" : [{
  "name" : "Software",
  "size" : 89544
  }]
},
{
  "name" : "Insurance",
  "children" : [{
  "name" : "Software",
  "size" : 10640
  }]
},
{
  "name" : "Transportation",
  "children" : [{
  "name" : "Software",
  "size" : 680
  }]
},


{
  "name" : "Healthcare",
  "children" : [{
  "name" : "Software",
  "size" : 25896
  }]
},
{
  "name" : "Manufacturing",
  "children" : [{
  "name" : "Services",
  "size" : 2324
  }]
},
{
  "name" : "Financial Services",
  "children" : [{
  "name" : "Software",
  "size" : 21280
  }]
},
{
  "name" : "Healthcare",
  "children" : [{
  "name" : "Software",
  "size" : 1404
  }]
},
{
  "name" : "Services",
  "children" : [{
  "name" : "Software",
  "size" : 11664
  }]
},
{
  "name" : "Healthcare",
  "children" : [{
  "name" : "Software",
  "size" : 23120
  }]
},
{
  "name" : "Tobacco",
  "children" : [{
  "name" : "Software",
  "size" : 5760
  }]
},
{
  "name" : "Transportation",
  "children" : [{
  "name" : "Software",
  "size" : 8064
  }]
},
{
  "name" : "Retail",
  "children" : [{
  "name" : "Software",
  "size" : 224960
  }]
},
{
  "name" : "Financial Services",
  "children" : [{
  "name" : "Maintenance",
  "size" : 1155
  }]
},
{
  "name" : "Automotives",
  "children" : [{
  "name" : "Software",
  "size" : 34592
  }]
},
{
  "name" : "Computer Hardware",
  "children" : [{
  "name" : "Maintenance",
  "size" : 1651.2
  }]
},
{
  "name" : "Transportation",
  "children" : [{
  "name" : "Software",
  "size" : 10920
  }]
},
{
  "name" : "Insurance",
  "children" : [{
  "name" : "Maintenance",
  "size" : 142.5
  }]
},
{
  "name" : "Transportation",
  "children" : [{
  "name" : "Software",
  "size" : 10920
  }]
},
{
  "name" : "Communication",
  "children" : [{
  "name" : "Software",
  "size" : 2560
  }]
},
{
  "name" : "Oil & Gas",
  "children" : [{
  "name" : "Software",
  "size" : 180048
  }]
},
{
  "name" : "Computer Hardware",
  "children" : [{
  "name" : "Software",
  "size" : 1248
  }]
},
{
  "name" : "Healthcare",
  "children" : [{
  "name" : "Software",
  "size" : 10976
  }]
},
{
  "name" : "Computer Software",
  "children" : [{
  "name" : "Software",
  "size" : 2160
  }]
},
{
  "name" : "Transportation",
  "children" : [{
  "name" : "Software",
  "size" : 1704
  }]
},
{
  "name" : "Oil & Gas",
  "children" : [{
  "name" : "Software",
  "size" : 4416
  }]
},
{
  "name" : "Insurance",
  "children" : [{
  "name" : "Software",
  "size" : 10200
  }]
},
{
  "name" : "Insurance",
  "children" : [{
  "name" : "Services",
  "size" : 1386
  }]
},
{
  "name" : "Computer Hardware",
  "children" : [{
  "name" : "Software",
  "size" : 38800
  }]
},
{
  "name" : "Pharmaceutical",
  "children" : [{
  "name" : "Maintenance",
  "size" : 1296
  }]
},
{
  "name" : "Insurance",
  "children" : [{
  "name" : "Software",
  "size" : 22707
  }]
},
{
  "name" : "Insurance",
  "children" : [{
  "name" : "Services",
  "size" : 1701
  }]
},
{
  "name" : "Financial Services",
  "children" : [{
  "name" : "Software",
  "size" : 3840
  }]
},
{
  "name" : "Retail",
  "children" : [{
  "name" : "Maintenance",
  "size" : 1778.4
  }]
},
{
  "name" : "Telecommunication",
  "children" : [{
  "name" : "Software",
  "size" : 63984
  }]
},
{
  "name" : "Healthcare",
  "children" : [{
  "name" : "Software",
  "size" : 13509
  }]
},
{
  "name" : "Business Services",
  "children" : [{
  "name" : "Software",
  "size" : 7440
  }]
},
{
  "name" : "Computer Hardware",
  "children" : [{
  "name" : "Software",
  "size" : 311808
  }]
},
{
  "name" : "Computer Hardware",
  "children" : [{
  "name" : "Software",
  "size" : 2280
  }]
},
{
  "name" : "Healthcare",
  "children" : [{
  "name" : "Software",
  "size" : 768
  }]
},
{
  "name" : "Business Services",
  "children" : [{
  "name" : "Maintenance",
  "size" : 1036.8
  }]
},
{
  "name" : "Computer Hardware",
  "children" : [{
  "name" : "Software",
  "size" : 2280
  }]
},
{
  "name" : "Recreation",
  "children" : [{
  "name" : "Software",
  "size" : 133407
  }]
},
{
  "name" : "Business Services",
  "children" : [{
  "name" : "Software",
  "size" : 52688
  }]
},
{
  "name" : "Communication",
  "children" : [{
  "name" : "Software",
  "size" : 1488
  }]
},
{
  "name" : "Insurance",
  "children" : [{
  "name" : "Services",
  "size" : 5607
  }]
},
{
  "name" : "Computer Hardware",
  "children" : [{
  "name" : "Software",
  "size" : 648
  }]
},
{
  "name" : "Communication",
  "children" : [{
  "name" : "Services",
  "size" : 2960
  }]
},
{
  "name" : "Computer Hardware",
  "children" : [{
  "name" : "Software",
  "size" : 6408
  }]
},
{
  "name" : "Insurance",
  "children" : [{
  "name" : "Software",
  "size" : 10296
  }]
},
{
  "name" : "Manufacturing",
  "children" : [{
  "name" : "Maintenance",
  "size" : 2295
  }]
},
{
  "name" : "Transportation",
  "children" : [{
  "name" : "Maintenance",
  "size" : 1008
  }]
},
{
  "name" : "Distribution",
  "children" : [{
  "name" : "Software",
  "size" : 3200
  }]
},
{
  "name" : "Financial Services",
  "children" : [{
  "name" : "Software",
  "size" : 1968
  }]
},
{
  "name" : "Insurance",
  "children" : [{
  "name" : "Services",
  "size" : 23520
  }]
},
{
  "name" : "Transportation",
  "children" : [{
  "name" : "Software",
  "size" : 9184
  }]
},

{
  "name" : "Insurance",
  "children" : [{
  "name" : "Software",
  "size" : 4648
  }]
},
{
  "name" : "Business Services",
  "children" : [{
  "name" : "Services",
  "size" : 1743
  }]
},
{
  "name" : "Manufacturing",
  "children" : [{
  "name" : "Services",
  "size" : 1344
  }]
},
{
  "name" : "Business Services",
  "children" : [{
  "name" : "Software",
  "size" : 704
  }]
},



{
  "name" : "Insurance",
  "children" : [{
  "name" : "Software",
  "size" : 1248
  }]
},
{
  "name" : "Construction",
  "children" : [{
  "name" : "Services",
  "size" : 1932
  }]
},
{
  "name" : "Healthcare",
  "children" : [{
  "name" : "Maintenance",
  "size" : 2592
  }]
},
{
  "name" : "Business Services",
  "children" : [{
  "name" : "Maintenance",
  "size" : 5011.2
  }]
},
{
  "name" : "Distribution",
  "children" : [{
  "name" : "Software",
  "size" : 2208
  }]
},
{
  "name" : "Communication",
  "children" : [{
  "name" : "Software",
  "size" : 37696
  }]
},
{
  "name" : "Transportation",
  "children" : [{
  "name" : "Software",
  "size" : 11076
  }]
},
{
  "name" : "Healthcare",
  "children" : [{
  "name" : "Software",
  "size" : 27824
  }]
},
{
  "name" : "Insurance",
  "children" : [{
  "name" : "Software",
  "size" : 4851
  }]
},
{
  "name" : "Business Services",
  "children" : [{
  "name" : "Maintenance",
  "size" : 1932
  }]
},
{
  "name" : "Entertainment",
  "children" : [{
  "name" : "Maintenance",
  "size" : 199.2
  }]
},
{
  "name" : "Insurance",
  "children" : [{
  "name" : "Software",
  "size" : 29008
  }]
},
{
  "name" : "Oil & Gas",
  "children" : [{
  "name" : "Software",
  "size" : 5460
  }]
},
{
  "name" : "Pharmaceutical",
  "children" : [{
  "name" : "Software",
  "size" : 14400
  }]
},
{
  "name" : "Recreation",
  "children" : [{
  "name" : "Services",
  "size" : 9856
  }]
},
{
  "name" : "Distribution",
  "children" : [{
  "name" : "Software",
  "size" : 12160
  }]
},
{
  "name" : "Insurance",
  "children" : [{
  "name" : "Software",
  "size" : 28616
  }]
},
{
  "name" : "Financial Services",
  "children" : [{
  "name" : "Software",
  "size" : 8112
  }]
},
{
  "name" : "Entertainment",
  "children" : [{
  "name" : "Services",
  "size" : 71760
  }]
},
{
  "name" : "Business Services",
  "children" : [{
  "name" : "Software",
  "size" : 6720
  }]
},
{
  "name" : "Services",
  "children" : [{
  "name" : "Software",
  "size" : 38016
  }]
},
{
  "name" : "Manufacturing",
  "children" : [{
  "name" : "Software",
  "size" : 10296
  }]
},
{
  "name" : "Entertainment",
  "children" : [{
  "name" : "Maintenance",
  "size" : 2308.5
  }]
},
{
  "name" : "Manufacturing",
  "children" : [{
  "name" : "Software",
  "size" : 10528
  }]
},
{
  "name" : "Transportation",
  "children" : [{
  "name" : "Software",
  "size" : 2772
  }]
},
{
  "name" : "Distribution",
  "children" : [{
  "name" : "Software",
  "size" : 6912
  }]
},
{
  "name" : "Retail",
  "children" : [{
  "name" : "Software",
  "size" : 2040
  }]
},
{
  "name" : "Retail",
  "children" : [{
  "name" : "Services",
  "size" : 236880
  }]
},
{
  "name" : "Computer Software",
  "children" : [{
  "name" : "Software",
  "size" : 36192
  }]
},
{
  "name" : "Computer Hardware",
  "children" : [{
  "name" : "Software",
  "size" : 1312
  }]
},
{
  "name" : "Insurance",
  "children" : [{
  "name" : "Services",
  "size" : 658
  }]
},
{
  "name" : "Financial Services",
  "children" : [{
  "name" : "Software",
  "size" : 10920
  }]
},
{
  "name" : "Transportation",
  "children" : [{
  "name" : "Software",
  "size" : 5760
  }]
},
{
  "name" : "Insurance",
  "children" : [{
  "name" : "Services",
  "size" : 5418
  }]
},
{
  "name" : "Telecommunication",
  "children" : [{
  "name" : "Software",
  "size" : 3920
  }]
},
{
  "name" : "Manufacturing",
  "children" : [{
  "name" : "Software",
  "size" : 11560
  }]
},
{
  "name" : "Transportation",
  "children" : [{
  "name" : "Software",
  "size" : 702
  }]
},
{
  "name" : "Business Services",
  "children" : [{
  "name" : "Services",
  "size" : 1800
  }]
},
{
  "name" : "Technology",
  "children" : [{
  "name" : "Maintenance",
  "size" : 196.8
  }]
},
{
  "name" : "Insurance",
  "children" : [{
  "name" : "Software",
  "size" : 6016
  }]
},

{
  "name" : "Transportation",
  "children" : [{
  "name" : "Software",
  "size" : 11076
  }]
}

]
}
```

I am currently getting following errors as below:-

> 1. Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
> 2. XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///home/harsha/Desktop/test.json. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.
> 3. Uncaught #
> 4. Uncaught NetworkError: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load 'file:///home/harsha/Desktop/test.json'.

Comment: Your JSON seems to have errors

Comment: Can you please elaborate the json error as i am new to d3 and i have csv with 3 columns:- Industry type ,Opportunity and Amount and the requirement is to create a treemap like:- "Put a filet by withor loss or a radio button

First level should be industry by amount 
Drill down to oppourtunity type  by amount "